# What temperature is really required to make fused quartz?

Tags: glass

Glass transition temperature of fused quartz is 1200 °C. Does this mean it can be made by heating sand to 1200 °C, or does the melting point of $\ce{SiO2}$ has to be reached (~1700 °C) for that to happen?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_transition#:~:text=Dry%20nylon%2D6%20has%20a,C%20(117%20%C2%B0F).) for glass transition temperatures.

Comment: Most "glass" is not pure quartz (which is silicon dioxide). Usually many other ingredients are added to lower the melting temperature and/or to make the properties different.

Comment: Fused silica is not the same as fused quartz. Fused silica fluorescence cuvettes are an example. Even high purity natural quartz crystals have significant levels of impurities, e.g., aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

Glass is not necessarily made of pure silica $\ce{SiO2}.$ Ordinary glass is a mixture of at least $50\,\%$ $\ce{SiO2},$ plus smaller proportions of $\ce{CaO},$ $\ce{Na2O},$ $\ce{K2O},$ and $\ce{Al2O3},$ with impurities like $\ce{Fe2O3}.$ Pyrex has also some $\ce{B2O3}.$

Glass has no defined melting point. It becomes like a very viscous paste at around 800 °C. Mixtures have melting points that are always much lower than their components.

Comment: Is explicitly stated im talking about quartz glass, which is 100% silica. I'll change it to fused quartz to avoid such misunderstandings